# adding a result of a calculation to a span with javascript (jQuery) after a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi  I wrote something JQ but i'm not sure is correct :) so would like you to help me figure out how

1.When the user clicks the button (Show results)

2.the two figures are added together and the result is displayed in the span # result

3.check on user input, as a warning, if there is no number entered into the text boxes

only pure jQuery please :)
Thank you in advance for your help.
http://jsfiddle.net/4ke8k5vp/

```
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <p>
        <input type="text" id="num1" placeholder="Enter a number" value="" /> 
        + 
        <input type="text" id="num2" placeholder="Enter a number more" value="" /> 
        = 
        <span class="alert" id="result"></span>
    </p>

    <input type="button" value="Show results"  />



</div>
```

```
 $(document).ready(function () {


            var num1 = $('#num1');
            var num2 = $('#num2');
            var total = num1 + num2;

            $(":button").click(function () {

                $("span").html();


            });







    });
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4ke8k5vp/1/

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/P3gvXax.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you javascript you need to cast `$('#num1')` and `$('#num2')` to int or float with `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` before adding them.
Also, in your html, the input type should be *number*, not *text*.

The whole javascript funtion should be more like this

```
$(":button").click(function () {
    var num1 = $('#num1').val();
    var num2 = $('#num2').val();
    if (num1 == "" or num2 == "") alert("Please fill both inputs");
    else {
        var total = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
        $("span").text(total);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var num1 = $('#num1');
     var num2 = $('#num2');

     $(":button").click(function () {
         // Update the total each time the button is clicked.
         // Use `parseInt` to convert the string to an integer. Add them.
         var total = parseInt(num1.val(), 10) + parseInt(num2.val(), 10);

        // Pass the total to the html
        $("span").html(total);
    });
});
```

There are a couple of other things you could do to optimize your code, such as adding IDs to the button and the span, but that's outside of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lon5wp7t/

I broke this down for you so you could hopefully learn from the code! The end of this post will give you what you want, but I've gone through to illustrate how we get to that point!

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
 // do whatever
});
```

The above part of the code tells the computer to work what's between the brackets when the document is loaded

```
$(":button").click(function () { 
// do whatever
});
```

The above adds what's called an "Event Listener" to anything labeled as a button, when that event is triggered it works whatever is between the brackets. In this case it is the "click" event.

You were correct on putting these two together, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

  $(":button").click(function () { 
  // do whatever
  });

});
```

So what we have so far is that, when the document is loaded, the script adds an event listener to anything labeled button. It doesn't do anything(you'll notice the "//do whatever" is just a comment) but we can certainly fix that.

On click we want the values to be pulled from the input boxes.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

  $(":button").click(function () { 

  var num1 = $('#num1').val();
  var num2 = $('#num2').val();

  });

});
```

Great! Now when the button is clicked, it pulls the input and puts it into 2 variables, num1 and num2. However, when you pull the input you have to realize that what you are pulling from the input boxes are STRINGS. Strings are not recognized as being able to be added. If num1 was equal to 2 and num2 was equal to 3, when you added them together instead of "5" you would get "23". They are concatenated and not computed for a sum. To change that we have to change the input from STRINGS to INTEGERS. We can do this by using the function parseInt() - which will read a string and return an integer.

```
  $(document).ready(function () { 

  $(":button").click(function () { 

  var num1 = $('#num1').val();
  var num2 = $('#num2').val();
  var total = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
  });

});
```

Finally we have a total, all we have left to do is put it into the span tag!

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

  $(":button").click(function () { 

  var num1 = $('#num1').val();
  var num2 = $('#num2').val();
  var total = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
  $("span").html(total);
  });

});
```